# Java delete not deleting

Tags: java, file-io, directory

I am writing some code that deletes all the files in a directory, so far I have:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class Delete {

    public void DeleteFiles() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Called deleteFiles");
        File file = new File("D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/build/web/resources/pdf/up617648/");

        String[] myFiles;
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            myFiles = file.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < myFiles.length; i++) {
                File myFile = new File(file, myFiles[i]);
                System.out.println(myFile);
                myFile.delete();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When I call this I can see all the files are called etc but nothing ever gets deleted, why is this, this is what I get in the console:

```
INFO: Called deleteFiles
INFO: D:\Documents\NetBeansProjects\printing~subversion\fileupload\build\web\resources\pdf\up617648\1.png
INFO: D:\Documents\NetBeansProjects\printing~subversion\fileupload\build\web\resources\pdf\up617648\lecture04_A_slides.pdf
```

All the files in the path are deleted, yet in Netbeans I can still see the files in the resources folder, even though the direct path to this folder is empty, I have done a clean build.

This is a bit weird, it deletes the files from the directory fine, in Netbeans it still shows up the files, restart netbeans and then the files appear back into the directory.

Comment: Maybe your program isn't running with sufficient permissions to delete the files?

Comment: i have added an edit, it deletes the files from the folder, but in netbeans, resource/pdf/up... i can still see the files even though using the direct path has not files

Comment: Netbeans updates its view of the filesystem when it wants to. :) It is not reliable.

Comment: Build the jar. Close NetBeans. Run the program. View the result.

Comment: Thanks have done and have updated the qustion with the new issue

Comment: [`File#delete()` returns a boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete()). Please make a habit of putting a check in your code to ensure the file was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Windows file system isn't really friendly to the way Java does deletions. Most likely something else holds a reference/handle to that file which makes Windows prevent its deletion. This something may be quite literally anything, even the JVM itself if you've touched the same file previously and haven't cleaned up resources properly.

Comment: `Windows file system isn't really friendly to the way Java does deletions.` - If true, may be this should be reworded as Java does not implement deletions on Windows well.

Comment: That's a Windows behavior to prevent file deletion that is in currently use. That is not a wrong java implementation.